# How to create tar archive split into, or spanning, multiple files?

Tags: linux, tar

According to [this page](http://paulbradley.tv/44/), one can let tar create a tar archive "split" into 100 Mb files:

```
tar -c -M --tape-length=102400 --file=disk1.tar largefile.tgz
```

The problem is that this command will require you to interactively give a new filename for the next file, after the first file is filled.

Anybody knows of a way to skip this interactive step, and let tar do the "splitting" automatically?

Comment: Related to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61774/6860

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at the `--new-volume-script` option, which lets you replace the prompting mechanism with a different mechanism or with a generated filename.  (`(tar.info)Multi-Volume Archives` in the `tar` info page.)  The problem with `split` is that you need to `cat` the pieces back together to do anything, whereas a multivolume archive should be a bit more flexible.

Comment: That's true, of course.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! I now found out that there is actually some instructions (incl. example) available here: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#Using-Multiple-Tapes

Comment: The problem with this is that it's overly involved nonsense and promotes the opposite of proper Unix style apps.

Answer (score 40):

You can use split for this:

```
tar czpvf - /path/to/archive | split -d -b 100M - tardisk
```

This tells tar to send the data to stdout, and split to pick it from stdin - additionally using a numeric suffix (`-d`), a chunk size (`-b`) of 100M and using 'tardisk' as the base for the resulting filenames (tardisk00, tardisk01, tardisk02, etc.).

To extract the data afterwards you can use this:

```
cat tardisk* | tar xzpvf -
```

Comment: Small correction, `-d` is for numeric suffix, not prefix.

Answer (score 8):

Of course the best option to use is the `--new-volume-script` option.

But, if you know the size of the file (in this case, largefile.tgz), then you can do this also:

```
tar -c -M -L 102400 --file=disk1.tar --file=disk2.tar --file=disk3.tar largefile.tgz
```

Summary:

```
-c = Create
-M = multi-volume
-L 102400 = 100MB files (disk1.tar, disk2.tar, disk3.tar ...)
```

(For the -L, specify as many as needed so that the total sum of the tar files is larger than largefile.tgz)

If you are trying to `tar` a directory tree structure

Answer (score 6):

it will automatically  create files of size 1.1GB, if your tar is bigger in size, you can increase the number, for an example 1000 {2..1000} or you can increase the input to tape-length argument.

```
tar --tape-length=1048576 -cMv --file=tar_archive.{tar,tar-{2..100}} backup.tar.lzma
```

Answer (score 5):

I've answered here with the better explanation here [tar split archive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676119/13373)

**TLDR;**

This command is creating 2GB chunks without the compression:

```
tar -cv --tape-length=2097000 --file=my_archive-{0..50}.tar file1 file2 dir3
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest non-interactive way would be -

Creating multipart tar from a large file (say bigfile)

```
$ tar cvf small.tar -L1024 -F 'echo small.tar-${TAR_VOLUME} >&${TAR_FD}' bigfile
```

Extracting multipart tar to a specific directory (say /output/dir)

```
$ tar xvf small.tar -F 'echo small.tar-${TAR_VOLUME} >&${TAR_FD}' -C /output/dir
```

You are free to select any supported compression format, block size (1024K here) and archive name (which is small.tar here).

Comment: Works pretty well

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the following commands:

```
mkdir -p ./split
rm -rf ./split/*
tar -cML 102400 -F 'cp "${TAR_ARCHIVE}" \
    ./split/part_${TAR_VOLUME}.tar' \
    -f split/part_1.tar large_file.tar.gz
```

The only problem is that `part_1.tar` will actually be the last file, and the others are shifted by one. I.e. `part_2.tar` is actually the first part, and `part_k.tar` is the `(n - 1)`<sup>th</sup> part. Fixing this with some shell script is trivial, and left as an exercise for the reader.