# Gzip'd tar archive Spanning Multiple Disks

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

Very similar to ([How to create tar archive split into, or spanning, multiple files?](https://superuser.com/questions/290986/how-to-create-tar-archive-split-into-or-spanning-multiple-files)), but specifically I would like to simultaneously:

- tar and compress a 10 tb directory, having insufficient local space to store that file
- use as a target 3 different USB-attached 4 tb hard drives (`/dev/sdl1 /dev/sdm1 /dev/sdn1`)

`tar -cMz -f /dev/sdl1 -f /dev/sdm1 -f /dev/sdn1 /share/CACHEDEV2_DATA/Data/`

Throws me

`tar: Cannot use multi-volume compressed archives`

Do I heed that error and give up?

Comment: Try without the `-z` and also have a look at flag `-L`